# What is the source of noise in this current measurement?

Tags: motor, current-measurement

I'm measuring the current through a [100W motor](https://product.mabuchi-motor.com/detail.html?id=116) with a 50A current sensor and I'm getting reasonably good data but there's also a fair amount of noise:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016M6IHSM) is the current sensor I'm using. It measures current on the high side of the motor coming from a 3s1p lithium ion battery pack. To collect the data, I'm using the 10-bit ADC on an Arduino nano and saving it to an SD card the sampling rate is about 30ms.

There is no PWM controlling the motor, only a switch.

Is this normal for motor current data? If I used the 30A current sensor (instead of 50A) would the data be less noisy? Where is this noise coming from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the sample rate? The scale of the x-axis is too large to say anything about the noise. Could you post a screen with 100ms across the x-axis? My first guess is that you're measuring a 50Hz hum imposed on the signal. It could also be commutator noise, but first post some better graphs!

Comment: Sampling rate is about 30ms - added graphs with smaller scale.

Comment: It's a brushed permanent magnet DC motor. That's commutator noise. A large capacitor across the motor will quiet it somewhat. Alternatively or additionally, put a lowpass filter between the current sensor and your ADC.

Comment: Scope the signal directly and adjust the time scale until you can see the frequency content of the signal. Have you added the jumper for the low-pass filter option?

Answer (score 1):

It's the noise from the commutation. Put capacitors on the power feed,  and low pass the ADC